# Why won't checkboxes display in my WPF Listbox containing checkboxes?

Tags: .net, wpf

I am using AvaloniaUI (WPF) to build a simple form with a Listbox.
I would like to have a checkbox appear for each item in the Listbox.
The values in the Listbox are hardwired.
The text displays as expected.
I cannot get the checkboxes to appear for each of my ListBox items.

**Here is a sample code snippet of my Listbox definition.**

```
<DockPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="Test"
              DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel Margin="-10, 0, 0, 0">
                    <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                              IsChecked="True" />
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                               Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"
                               TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="{Binding}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBoxItem Content="One" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="Two" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="Three" />
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Why don't the checkboxes display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why don't the checkboxes display?

Because the `ItemTemplate` isn't applied to `ListBoxItem` elements.

Change the type of the item to something else as suggested by @AndrewKeepCoding or use your `DataTemplate` as the `ContentTemplate` for the `ListBoxItem` elements that you create explicitly:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Test"
         DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
            <DockPanel Margin="-10, 0, 0, 0">
                <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                          IsChecked="True" />
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                               Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"
                               TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="{Binding}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBoxItem Content="One" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource template}" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Two" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource template}" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Three" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource template}" />
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ItemTemplate is not applied when you directly add ListBoxItems.

Changing it to `String`s should work:

```xml
<sys:String>One</sys:String>
<sys:String>Two</sys:String>
<sys:String>Three</sys:String>
```

You also might need to add the namespace for `sys`.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens. You are totally right. Updated my answer.